# Is it a good practice to use a recursive Map (Map of Maps)

Tags: java, data-structures

I found this old code snippet which uses a Map of Map of Map:

`Map<String, Map<Long, Map<String, String>>> sMap = null;`

Besides adding unnecessary complexity to the code, it is making it difficult to unit test the class.

However, my manager said it is a good practice to use Map of Map because it improves the efficiency of using the Map Container. Any thoughts ?

Comment: Is it good practice to use a hammer? If you want to drive in a nail, yes. If you want to install a window, probably not.

Comment: Efficiency does not matter when you are trying to understand the code, such construct wastes minimum hour of your time trying to understand what author meant...

Comment: See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/250124/nested-maps-vs-combined-keys
and https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/10-things-java-developer-should-know-hashmap-chinmay-parekh

Answer (score 1):

It depends. But I just want to mention an alternative here, which may or may not be better suited for your use case: have a single level of map, with a custom type of key.

```
class MyMapKey {
  public String a;
  public long b;
  public String c;
  // Implement equals() and hashCode() (or tell your IDE to do it)
}

Map<MyMapKey, String> sMap = null;
```

This generally saves you a lot of `null` checks when going down the levels of the map, so it simplifies the code. But you can no longer efficiently iterate over all items that have `a` set to `"zoidberg"`, for example.

Comment: I'd call this a 'MultiKey' design pattern. Very interesting. I'll try it in the future. I assume that the three attribute keys can be replaced with a single attribute List<String>, with the 1st entry being the primary key, the 2nd being a long-to-string, and the 3rd being the leaf node key.

Comment: @RannLifshitz At that point, you're almost describing a path through an arbitrary tree instead, so you could consider using a more tree-like data structure.

Answer (score 1):

It is not good practice to write code that's hard to maintain.

"Efficiency" is a common trap that wastes developer time (and money) because it's almost impossible to know what parts of a system need to be efficient—and exactly how efficient they need to be—before you have a working system and are actually able to *measure* things. Even then, running the code on better hardware is often cheaper than spending programmer time making things more efficient.

That said, the idea of a Map of Maps is valuable, and there are already classes that embed that concept in more programmer-friendly ways. For example, Guava's [Table](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Table.html) or perhaps even a [Multimap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) might be suitable.

You could also create collection-like classes *named in terms of the domain concepts* that use Maps internally, thus hiding the complexity and making the code more understandable.

Comment: A `Multimap` is merely a map that can contain the same key more than once; it's not related to maps of maps. A `Multimap` would be a replacement for a `Map` whose values are `List`s.